# Redirecionar para outra aplicação CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um CodeIgnter com 3 aplicacoes, dentro de cada uma o `welcome view` padrao, a estrutura esta parecida com isso:

- www
- applications

  - site
  - site2
  - site3
- system

Preciso descobrir como redirecionar para o site2 por exemplo a partir do site 1.

Comment: Cada uma tem o seu próprio endereço?

Comment: vai ser tipo sub.site.com ( site 1 )
sub.site.com/site2 
sub.site.com/site3

Comment: Vai dar choque na rota não vai?

Comment: A estrutura de pastas pensei esta, mas aceito outras sugestoes, preciso de 3 aplications no mesmo codeignter

Answer (score 1):

Adriano,

Uma sugestão é usar a função `header`, apontando para a URL do aplicação a ser redirecionada:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
header('Location: https://pt.stackoverflow.com');
```

É uma solução simples, nativa do PHP, que permite fazer redirecionamentos. [Para mais informações, a documentação do PHP explica mais alguns detalhes.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

Controller Site 1 para chamar site 2

```
 public function redirecionar() {
        redirect('nomecontrollersite2/indexsite2');
     }
```

Controller Site 2

```
  public function indexsite2() {
          $this->load->view('indexsite2',);
}
```

Comment: nao funcionou, sao aplicacoes diferentes